# Files are created on older locations after merge during Forward Integration at TFS?

Tags: tfs

We have a very simple branching pattern consisting of two branches.

[image: Project branching pattern]

The branch `Trunk` is used as the main production branch with bug-fixes and quick UI improvements, whereas `TrunkSplit` was used to split one big solution files into 6 smaller solutions.

However we faced problems during the Forward Integration (FI): even though for all changes TFS correctly showed the target file (despite renaming and moving to another folder), the merged files were created following the older folder structure.

[image: Folder structure after merge]

For example here you see that instead of merging the changes into `FieldManagement.UI` (down) the TFS created a new folder and placed the merged files there (up).

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this scenario on TFS2010. This is what I did:

I created a branch (A) with 2 folders:

```
-> Analysis (Folder)

      -> ABC (folder)

         -> hello.html (file)

-> Auth (folder)

       -> XYZ (Folder)
```

Now I created another branch from A called A-Branch. I moved the folder ABC from Analysis to the Auth folder as shown below:

```
-> Analysis (Folder)    


-> Auth (folder)

       -> ABC (folder)

         -> hello.html (file)

       -> XYZ (Folder)
```

Now I edited the file hello.html and added some new text in there. Merged the code from A to A-branch. As you mentioned, it rightly identified the target file and showed a conflict. I auto-resolved the conflict and it edited the file at the right location (Auth -> ABC -> hello.html) without any issues.

Are you doing anything different? or am i missing something?

Comment: This is really good experiment. I wish, I had liberty to do branching to concept-prove some branching related items.